# Comparing 2 columns in 2 csv files in Java

Tags: java, csv, compare

I have two csv both with a primary key, im trying to comapre both keys so that i can combine the related csvs to one with the correct keys, however for now i just wanted to compare what was in collumns one. My mind is a little blank i hope by the code you can sort of figure out the direction im going. im unable to get my arrays to actually take in the strings . Java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception

`import java.io.;
import java.util.;`

public class UDC {
    public void search(String [][] wat, String [][] ud){

```
}


public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    String [] [] cols = {};
    String [] [] cols1={};
    int row =0;
    int row1 =0;
    int j = 0;


/*Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Watford Update File.csv"));
Scanner c = new Scanner(new File("udc.csv"));
while (s.hasNextLine()){
    String line = s.nextLine();
    cols =line.split(",");
    System.out.println(cols[0]);*/
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file1.csv"));
    Scanner w = new Scanner (new File("file.csv"));
    while (w.hasNextLine())

    {
        String line1 = w.nextLine();    
        System.out.println(cols);
        //cols[row]=line1.split(",");
        row ++;
        if(!w.hasNextLine()){
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String line2 = s.nextLine();
         //cols1[row1]=line2.split(",");
        //put while loop in diffrent method but break


            if(cols[j].equals(cols1[row1]))
            {

                j++;
                row1++;
                System.out.print(cols[j]);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(cols1[row1]);
                System.out.println();

            }else{
                row1++;

            }

        }


    }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are both columns the same size? If not, you could get this exception on the line `if (cols[j].equals(cols1[row1]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using arrays for `cols` and `cols1`, you should use `List<String[]>`. Also, your code is very confusing because you have the comparison loop(s?) intertwined with the reading loops. It would be better to simply read in the data first and then do your comparisons.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    List<String[]> cols;
    List<String[]> cols1;
    try {
        cols = readFile("udc.csv");
        cols1 = readFile("Watford Update File.csv");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    // loop through array lists to do your comparisons
    // For example, to compare the first column of rows i and j:
    //    cols.get(i)[0].equals(cols1.get(j)[0])
}

private static List<String[]> readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("udc.csv"));
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        values.add(line.split(","));
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: @jbel - You were assigning an empty array to `cols` and `cols1` and did not have any provision to make the arrays grow. A `List` automatically grows, which is why I recommend it; otherwise you will have to implement your own reallocation routines for `cols` and `cols1`.

Comment: the next step would be to actually compare the two fields and and write on to the first csv file for e.g if i had two collumns in one csv i plan to add two more with the header matching up the unique numbers, ive been looking into the supercsv library but with what has been given to me it doesnt look if its possible .